# Compare two datatable rows to two ints in any order

Tags: c#

I'm doing some comparison, I have datatable with one text column, and I compare each row of datatable with all others.

My point is to avoid double comparison.

I thought writing IDs of compared rows to other datatable, so every time I can check if that two rows are already compared.

```
Table of already compared rows:
------
1245 4589
5589 6952
2233 2339
```

So if I want to compare rows with ids 6952 and 5589, I want to see if there is row with columns 6952/5589 or 5589/6952 in table of already compared rows.

What is the simpliest way?

Comment: Create an index and use SQL to find duplicates, it's going to be faster than anything that you can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add another string column which stores compared column IDs in delimited.

```
i.e. ,1234,5434,32453,
```

So you just have a string comparison. Compare **,ID,** with that column's value